# Groupby and fill data into a text template in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a small dataset as follow:

```
   id  city  price  area
0   1     a     12     6
1   2     a      3     7
2   3     a      3     8
3   4     b      2     9
4   5     b      5     6
```

I would like to groupby `city` and fill the data into a text template as follows:

For 【】 city, it has 【】district, 【】district and 【】district, the price is respectively 【】dollars, 【】dollars and【】dollar, the area sold is respectively 【】㎡，【】㎡ and 【】㎡.

Code:

```
df.groupby('city')['district'].apply(list)
Out[14]: 
city
bj    [hd, cy, tz]
sh        [hp, pd]
Name: district, dtype: object

df.groupby('city')['price'].apply(list)
Out[15]: 
city
bj    [12, 3, 3]
sh        [2, 5]
Name: price, dtype: object

df.groupby('city')['area'].apply(list)
Out[16]: 
city
bj    [6, 7, 8]
sh       [9, 6]
Name: area, dtype: object
```

For example, the result will be like this:

For **bj** city, it has **hd district, cy district and tz district**, the price is respectively **12 dollars, 3 dollars and 3 dollar**, the area sold is respectively **6 ㎡，7 ㎡ and 8 ㎡**.

Is it possible I could get an **approximate result (not necessary be exact same)** as above with Python? Many thanks for Python or Pandas masters' kind help at advance.

Comment: Is there a `city` field in your test data?

Comment: Sorry for the typo error, I modified.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I think I have your answer, hang on.  You will probably need to tweak it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
            dict(id = [1,2,3,4,5,],
                 city = list("a" * 3) +  list("b" * 2),
                 district = ["hd", "cy", "tz", "hp", "pd",],
                 price = [12,3,3,2,5,],
                 area = [6,7,8,9,6,],)
            )

# We can set a few initial variables to help the process out.
target = ["city",]
ignore = ["id",]

# This will produce -> ['district', 'price', 'area']
groupers = [i for i in df.columns if not i in tuple(target + ignore)]

# Iterate through each unique city value.
for c in df["city"].unique():
    # Start our message.
    msg = f"For city '{c}'," # I tweaked the formatting here.

    # Subset of data based on target variable (in this case, 'city')
    # Use `.drop_duplicates()` to retain unique rows.
    dft = df.loc[df["city"] == c, groupers].drop_duplicates()

    # --- OR, the following to use the `target` variable value. --- #
    # dft = df.loc[df[target[0]] == c, groupers].drop_duplicates()

    # Iterate a transposed index
    for idx in dft.T.index:

        # Make a quick value variable for clarity
        vals = dft.T.loc[idx].values

        # Do some ad hoc formatting for each specific field, if required
        # Add your desired message start to the respective variable.
        # `field` will be what is output to the message string.
        if idx == "price":
            msg_start = "the price is respectively "
            field = "dollars"
        elif idx == "area":
            msg_start = "the area sold is respectively "
            field = "m\u00b2"
        else:
            msg_start = " it has\n"
            field = idx

        # Add the message start section
        msg += msg_start

        # Use .join() with conditions to determine if the item is the last one in the list.
        msg += ", ".join([f"{i} {field}" if i != vals[-1] else f"and {i} {field}" for i in vals])

        # Add a newline for separation betweeen each set of items.
        msg += "\n"
    print(msg)
```

Output:

```
For city 'a', it has
hd district, cy district, and tz district
the price is respectively 12 dollars, and 3 dollars, and 3 dollars
the area sold is respectively 6 m², 7 m², and 8 m²

For city 'b', it has
hp district, and pd district
the price is respectively 2 dollars, and 5 dollars
the area sold is respectively 9 m², and 6 m²
```

Comment: no prob. I actually did a quick edit to only assign unique rows to `dft`.  I was teetering on whether to include it, but I don't see why you wouldn't since you don't want to list the same district, price, etc., more than once.